# How to resume download of file with dynamically changing download link?

Tags: windows, software-rec

Yesterday, i was downloading [Hall Of Mirrors](http://hom.paynereactor.com/download.html) from ausgamers. Later on I forgot that i am downloading something and i switched off my system, when i realized that i found that the file was downloaded till 65% and now it could not be resumed as the link was changed. I tried changing its .cfg files with no success.
It happens with me many a times. Is it possible to resume in such cases? Isn't it possible to tell the downloader that now the download link is changed? I am using [Gigaget](http://download.cnet.com/Gigaget-Download-Manager/3000-2071_4-10503294.html) but your answer is not required to be restricted to this app. I will download other software if that support such resuming functionality.

Answer (score 2):

[Aria2c](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) is a popular tool for this. If you use the "-c" switch it may even be able to recover what you've already downloaded with Gigaget so long it's sequential.